# Jquery innerHTML split

Tags: javascript, function

After long try I am posting this question.I am trying to add data using innerHTML in javascript.It is adding data but not in proper format as follow:
Html code:

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="changeSupplier">
     <table  class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="refreshtbody">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;">Company Name</th>
                <th style="background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;">Supplier Code</th>
                <th style="background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;">Person Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${supplierlst}" var="supplier">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ${supplier.var1}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${supplier.var2}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${supplier.var3}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("changeSupplier").innerHTML="";

var list = document.getElementById("changeSupplier");

list.innerHTML += "<table  class='table table-striped table-condensed' id='refreshtbody'><thead><tr>"+
                  "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Company Name</th>"+
                  "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Supplier Code</th>"+
                  "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Person Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

for(var i = 0, size = response.length; i < size ; i++){
    var iterator = response[i];
    //alert(supplier.companyName);
    list.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+iterator.var1+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var2+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var3+"</td></tr>";      
}

list.innerHTML += "</tbody></table>";
```

First time loading page it looks great in table format with tr.But after calling javascript function to append through innerHTML it is not coming inside table.

Please suggest something.

Comment: You're appending the HTML instantly and the Browser fixes the "errors". In this case the browser closes your `</tbody>` tag. You should append your HTML at once in the end of you script. [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/Xt8T8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You should add `</tr>` to the end of the `list.innerHTML` in `for` loop plus,</strike>

Write your html into another variable, after you have done with creating html format, assign it to the `list.innerHTML`;

**-ADDED CODE-**

```
var list = "";

list += "<table class='table table-striped table-condensed' id='refreshtbody'><thead><tr>"+
              "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Company Name</th>"+
              "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Supplier Code</th>"+
              "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Person Name</th>/tr></thead><tbody>";

for(var i = 0, size = response.length; i < size ; i++){
    var iterator = response[i];
    //alert(supplier.companyName);
    list += "<tr><td>"+iterator.var1+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var2+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var3+"</td></tr>";      
}

list += "</tbody></table>";
document.getElementById("changeSupplier").innerHTML = list;
```

Comment: i have updated my question it is there already in code.While posting I missed to write.

Comment: @Pagy Did you tried with another variable? I mean: `var test = "<table><thead>....</tbody></table>";` and call `document.getElementById("changeSupplier").innerHTML = test;`

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the error because in your for loop you never close the tr elements in your tbody. Incorrect nesting of html tags will break the display. Change it to:

`list.innerHTML = "<tr><td>"+iterator.var1+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var2+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var3+"</td></tr>";`

**Edit after an update from Pragy:**

After alexP's suggestion of using a variable to save the html before placing it on the page.
The final result should look like this:

```
document.getElementById("changeSupplier").innerHTML="";

var list = document.getElementById("changeSupplier");
var snip = '';

snip += "<table  class='table table-striped table-condensed' id='refreshtbody'><thead><tr>"+
                  "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Company Name</th>"+
                  "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Supplier Code</th>"+
                  "<th style='background-color: #1B98C8; color: white;'>Person Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

for(var i = 0, size = response.length; i < size ; i++){
    var iterator = response[i];
    //alert(supplier.companyName);
    snip  += "<tr><td>"+iterator.var1+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var2+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+iterator.var3+"</td></tr>";      
}

snip  += "</tbody></table>";
list.innerHTML = snip;
```

Comment: sorry it is there while posting i have forgot to add it.

Comment: In that case alexP is correct, you should create a temporary variable, and then add all the html to it (I usually call mine snip) and then just assign it to list.innerHTML after your loop

Comment: if I give variable inside forloop and use it after closing it will give me last record from list.

Comment: You don't make the variable in the for loop. You create it just below the line you declare list `var snip = '';` then after that, replace all your `list.innerHTML += ...` with `snip += ...`. Then just after the for loop, `list.innerHTML = snip`